# How do I PARTITION_BY multiple column names in a Column table?

Tags: snappydata

This documentation states:

http://snappydatainc.github.io/snappydata/rowAndColumnTables/

*"Use the PARTITION_BY {COLUMN} clause to provide a set of column names that will determine the partitioning"*

I want the following columns to be the partition keys: **id_** and **time_** .

```
CREATE TABLE EXAMPLE_COLUMN_TABLE (     id_ VARCHAR(64),    name_ VARCHAR(128),     time_ TIMESTAMP,    number_ INTEGER     ) USING column  OPTIONS(PARTITION_BY 'time_, id_', buckets '113', PERSISTENT 'ASYNCHRONOUS');
```

When I run this, it says everything is fine, however, if I do a **snappy>describe example_column_table**, time_ and id_ still show up as IS_NULLABLE = YES.

If I do only PARTIION_BY 'time_', and then do a **snappy> describe example_column_table**, that column shows as IS_NULLABLE = NO.

So, I am concerned that multiple column name partitioning is not working?

Answer (score 1):

The column table partitioning works fine even if you specify multiple partition columns. You can verify through query plan that both the columns will be picked as partitioning columns.

The IS_NULLABLE problem is specific to CLOB (VARCHAR) column type. Can you please try following DDL where the second partitioning column number_ is not a CLOB and it also becomes IS_NULLABLE --> NO

snappy> CREATE TABLE EXAMPLE_COLUMN_TABLE2 (     id_ VARCHAR(64),    name_ VARCHAR(128),     time_ TIMESTAMP,    number_ INTEGER     ) USING column  OPTIONS(PARTITION_BY 'time_, number_', buckets '113', PERSISTENT 'ASYNCHRONOUS');